# Copy directory on destination machine during .deb installation in Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit

Tags: deployment, cmake, ubuntu-14.04, packaging, deb

I just want to copy directory (which contains some files) on destination machine during .deb installation at path /opt/myProjectName in Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit.

Right now I am successfully able to install files on destination machine during .deb installation using CMakeLists.txt file as per below.

**INSTALL(FILES myShFile.sh DESTINATION /opt/myProjectName)**

But now I want to copy a directory (which contains some files) on destination machine at path **/opt/myProjectName**.

If anyone has idea about the same then please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: With [File:Copy](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html).

Comment: Thanks Joel for your reply. But as per your suggested way I am able to copy the directory only at my machine during build it with cmake and make. But  I want to copy the directory during deb installation on machine where we install deb on different machines (not on my machine only).

Comment: I have created a file in debian directory named "mypackagename.install" and write test  opt/myProjectName into it. Here "test" is the directory which I want to install with deb installation at destination machine at /opt/myProjectName path and it fixed my issue.